# Reading an imported text file

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

I'm trying to read a text file I've imported in Eclipse, but it gives me a FileNotFoundException even though I've imported it to the same source folder as the code. It works when I write the path of the text file but not when I only write the name of the file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Text {
public static void main(String [] args) {
    String un;
    int pass;

    // The name of the file to open or path.
    String fileName = "Pass.txt";

    String line = null;

    System.out.println("Welcome, please enter the username and password to read the content of the file");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Username?:");
    un = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Password?:");
    pass = scan.nextInt();

    if(un.equals("Hudhud") && pass==123){
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            while((line= bf.readLine()) !=null){
                System.out.println(line);
        }   

        // close file after reading
        bf.close();       

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");               
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '"+ fileName + "'");                   

    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("Dude, you ain't got rights to open this file");
  }
 }
}
```

EDIT

```
public class Text {
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
    String un;
    int pass;

    // The name of the file to open or path.
    String fileName = "Pass.txt";

    String line = null;


    System.out.println("Welcome, please enter the username and password to read the content of the file");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Username?:");
    un = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Password?:");
    pass = scan.nextInt();
    Class cls = Class.forName("com.demo.Text");
    ClassLoader cLoader = cls.getClassLoader();
    URL url = cLoader.getResource("Pass.txt");

    if(un.equals("Hudhud") && pass==123){
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File(url.getFile()));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
            jta.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40));
            frame.getContentPane().add(jta);
            frame.setSize(370,100);
            jta.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                jta.append(line);

            // close file after reading
            br.close();       

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");               
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '"+ fileName + "'");                   

        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Dude, you ain't got rights to open this file");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Probably it trying to read from user Directory...

Comment: if file is in your project path use `Class.getResourceAsStream` to open it

Comment: What is proj structure now.

Comment: http://i57.tinypic.com/wlavrr.png

Comment: @Satya, have you seen the pic?

Comment: @Satya: http://www.filedropper.com/capture_6

Comment: I've placed both Text.java and Pass.txt files in my current working dir (D:/info). Generated .class are in a package (D:/info/com.demo/). Its working for me. While running from CMD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer below. Its working fine for me. I put my class and text file is in **com/demo/** package. Later it will copied to **bin/com/demo/** folder automatically after .class file forms.

```
package com.demo;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.URL;

public class New {
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
    String un;
    int pass;

    // The name of the file to open or path.
    String fileName = "Pass.txt";

    String line = null;

    System.out.println("Welcome, please enter the username and password to read the content of the file");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Username?:");
    un = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Password?:");
    pass = scan.nextInt();
    Class cls = Class.forName("com.demo.New");
    ClassLoader cLoader = cls.getClassLoader();
    System.out.println(cLoader.getClass());
    URL url = cLoader.getResource("com/demo/Pass.txt");
    System.out.println("Value = " + url);

    if(un.equals("123") && pass==123){
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File(url.getFile()));
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            while((line= bf.readLine()) !=null){
                System.out.println(line);
        }   

        // close file after reading
        bf.close();       

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");               
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '"+ fileName + "'");                   

    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("Dude, you ain't got rights to open this file");
  }
 }
}
```

**O/P:**

```
  class sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader
  Value = file:/D:/info/satya1/abc/bin/com/demo/Pass.txt
```

Comment: @Bob see my answer here.

Comment: It says `Multiple markers at this line
 - Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException
 - Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be 
  parameterized` Have also put the pass.txt in the src folder and the class in the defeault package

Comment: It gives me a ClassNotFoundException. Here you got the project: http://i59.tinypic.com/11ju9mh.png

Comment: I still get an exception. Have you looked at the picture I linked?

Comment: @Bob, still getting exception. pic?

Comment: Yes but not in Eclipse I get it when I run the program in CMD. I've exported the project as a runnable jar and when I run it it asks for username/password and then it gives me the FileNotFoundException. Is it because I HAVE to use a gui or...?

Comment: So check the file path. Bcoz this is only foe eclipse. For command prompt place text file directly in class path (where .class files are generated). Use System.out.println("Value = " + url); statement to check file path.

Comment: Have placed the text file in the src folder but I get the FileNotFoundException

Comment: See comment clearly. put it in class path where all the .class files are located. Use System.out.println("Value = " + url); and see path what it's displays.

Comment: Value = file:/C:/Users/H/workspace/OpenText/bin/Pass.txt

Comment: So place it in bin folder. see here Value = file:/C:/Users/H/workspace/OpenText/bin/Pass.txt. Since you sre running from prompt. Because CMD will not copy any text file into bin folder. Eclipse only will do it.

Comment: If the given file located in the above path then why are you getting error. URL url = cLoader.getResource("Pass.txt"); and FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File(url.getFile()));. Thse two are there in your code exactly as is. If true placingtext file in bin is also correct.

Comment: Had you change any thing. Update it in your ?.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have added the file in the source directory, it depends on the configuration on Eclipse as to which is your program's working directory.
You can configure the working directory from the **run configurations ...** option.
You can also find out the working directory using this java line:

> System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
>                 System.getProperty("user.dir"));

Comment: It gives me `Working Directory = C:\Users\H\workspace\Login` which is the directory I'm working in

Comment: but is this the directory you have the file in also ?

Comment: No have the file on the desktop. I know I can change fileName to the path but i need to import because I want to export the project as a jar file. So I need the text file in the project.

Comment: Then you should put it to project's resources and open it with this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Pass.txt")

Comment: And where to I have to create the instance? Because it refers to the instance of the class